# How can I highlight the selected answer?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to highlight my selected answer.

I mean that all the answers I chose in each question will be highlighted in blue color. But as you can see in my code, when I select another answer in other question, the highlight of the previous question will be disappeared.
How can I fix that?

Thanks so much

```js
function openPresent(event) {
  const answer = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
  for (let i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    answer[i].style.backgroundColor = originalAnswerArray[i];
  }
  const input = event.currentTarget.querySelector("input")
  input.checked = true;
  event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

}

const answer = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
let i;

let originalAnswerArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
  originalAnswerArray.push(answer[i].getAttribute("name"));
  answer[i].addEventListener("click", openPresent);
}
```

```css
#attempt-quiz,
#review-quiz {
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#attempt-quiz p,
#review-quiz p {
  margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

form {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

.option,
.review-answer {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
}

.option:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

label {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="attempt-quiz">
  <div id="quiz" class="hidden">

    <p><strong> Question 1 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 1</p>
    <form name="ques01">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>

      </div>
    </form>

    <p><strong> Question 2 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 2</p>
    <form name='ques02'>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>
      </div>
    </form>

    <p><strong> Question 3 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 3</p>
    <form name="ques03">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>

      </div>
    </form>

    <p><strong> Question 4 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 4</p>
    <form name="ques04">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>

      </div>
    </form>

    <p><strong> Question 5 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 5</p>
    <form name="ques05">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>

      </div>
    </form>

    <p><strong> Question 6 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 6</p>
    <form name="ques06">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>

      </div>
    </form>

    <p><strong> Question 7 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 7

    </p>
    <form name="ques07">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>

      </div>
    </form>

    <p><strong> Question 8 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 8</p>
    <form name="ques08">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>

      </div>
    </form>

    <p><strong> Question 9 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 9</p>
    <form name="ques09">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>

      </div>
    </form>

    <p><strong> Question 10 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 10</p>
    <form name="ques10">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>

      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: If you want to keep the blue highlight, just remove the `for` loop in `openPresent`. If you want to keep selection, use checkboxes instead of radio buttons.

Comment: It is happening because you are taking all the option not just from the clicked question options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the "this" keyword.
for more information. please see the link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

For more clarification, I have wrote a sample code:

```js
function openPresent(event) {
    const input = this.querySelector("input")
    const name = input.getAttribute("name")
    input.checked = true;
    const otherAnswer = document.querySelectorAll(`[name="${name}"]`)
    for (i = 0; i < otherAnswer.length; i++) {
        otherAnswer[i].parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "#f1f1f1";
    }
    this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

const answer = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
for (i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    answer[i].addEventListener("click", openPresent);
}
```

```css
#attempt-quiz,
#review-quiz {
    width: 700px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#attempt-quiz p,
#review-quiz p {
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

form {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

.option,
.review-answer {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: relative;
}

.option:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

label {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="attempt-quiz">
            <div id="quiz" class="hidden">

                <p><strong> Question 1 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 1</p>
                <form name="ques01">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 2 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 2</p>
                <form name='ques02'>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 3 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 3</p>
                <form name="ques03">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question3" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 4 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 4</p>
                <form name="ques04">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question4" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 5 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 5</p>
                <form name="ques05">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question5" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 6 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 6</p>
                <form name="ques06">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question6" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 7 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 7

                </p>
                <form name="ques07">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question7" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 8 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 8</p>
                <form name="ques08">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question8" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 9 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 9</p>
                <form name="ques09">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question9" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <p><strong> Question 10 of 10</strong></p>
                <p>Question 10</p>
                <form name="ques10">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 1">
                        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>


                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 2">
                        <label>option 2</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 3">
                        <label>option 3</label><br>

                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" name="question10" value="option 4">
                        <label>option 4</label><br>

                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: It was great but it just works when I click on input. If I click outside the input and outcome, the input isn't checked. So, your code is pretty great but it is not all I want to solve this problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky but you can do it even with CSS only. I changed a bit the HTML structure but IT WORKS.

```css
#attempt-quiz,
#review-quiz {
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#attempt-quiz p,
#review-quiz p {
  margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

form {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

.option,
.review-answer {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
}

.option:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

label {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

/**/

.option {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.option input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 15px;
}

.option label {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

.option input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="attempt-quiz">
  <div id="quiz" class="hidden">
    <p><strong> Question 1 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 1</p>
    <form name="ques01">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="q1o1" name="question1" value="option 1">
        <label for="q1o1">option 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="q1o2" name="question1" value="option 2">
        <label for="q1o2">option 2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="q1o3" name="question1" value="option 3">
        <label for="q1o3">option 3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="q1o4" name="question1" value="option 4">
        <label for="q1o4">option 4</label>
      </div>
    </form>

    <p><strong> Question 2 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 2</p>
    <form name='ques02'>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="q2o1" name="question2" value="option 1">
        <label for="q2o1">option 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="q2o2" name="question2" value="option 2">
        <label for="q2o2">option 2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="q2o3" name="question2" value="option 3">
        <label for="q2o3">option 3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="q2o4" name="question2" value="option 4">
        <label for="q2o4">option 4</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You code problem is that it is selecting all `.option` instead from the selected question due to which only one of the all checked option has background color.

Here I first created `class="plzSelectMe"` for the form and select the options from the clicked `form`(question) . And add a `background-color` to it

```js
const answerForm = document.querySelectorAll(".plzSelectMe");
let j;
for (j = 0; j < answerForm.length; j++) {
  answerForm[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
    const answer = this.querySelectorAll(".option");
    for (let i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
      var radio = answer[i].querySelector("input")
      if (radio.checked) {
        answer[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      } else {
        answer[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
#attempt-quiz,
#review-quiz {
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#attempt-quiz p,
#review-quiz p {
  margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

.plzSelectMe {
  border: 2px solid red
}

form {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

.option,
.review-answer {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
}

.option:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

label {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section id="attempt-quiz">
  <div id="quiz" class="hidden">

    <p><strong> Question 1 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 1</p>
    <form name="ques01" class="plzSelectMe">

      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>
      </div>
      
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>

      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>
      </div>
      
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>
      </div>

    </form>

    <p><strong> Question 2 of 10</strong></p>
    <p>Question 2</p>
    <form name='ques02' class="plzSelectMe">

      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 1">
        <label><div >option 1 </div></label><br>
      </div>
      
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 2">
        <label>option 2</label><br>
      </div>
      
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 3">
        <label>option 3</label><br>
      </div>
      
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="option 4">
        <label>option 4</label><br>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
</section>
```